# Being logged in after CURL request and redirection php

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL on my site (site_my.com) to login to another page (site_another.com).

There's no problem with that, I could login remotely and getting responses/data from site_another.com .... but I'd like to achieve that, after the request via CURL if I redirect to the site_another.com ... I'd like to be logged in automatically.

What's the solution for that? (I'm using Codeigniter if it's relevant)

Comment: You'd need to be able to serve cookies from the other domain, which isn't possible if you're acting as a proxy.

Comment: I think OAuth protocol is the proper way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

on site 2, create a special 1-time token, that when accessed, gives the browser an authenticated cookie session, and have site 1 redirect the browser to that url. for security reasons, the tokens should be 1-time-use, generated with a cryptographically secure random generator (in php, that means random_bytes() in PHP7x or the openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() function with a $strong check in php5x), and should have sufficient length and short expiry time that guessing / bruteforcing /timing attacks are infeasible, eg `$token=base64_encode(random_bytes(20));`